# What is accessibility mode for (ctrl-m)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code has an accessibility mode that can be accessed using:

```
CTRL + M
```

What is the purpose of this mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It switches the behaviour of the `TAB` key.

When you are editing, the `TAB` key normally inserts a tab into the document. When you enable Accessibility Mode (`CTRL` + `M`) the `TAB` key will allow you to switch focus to another part of the editor.

This allows you to switch to another editing panel, the explore menu, your project files (and so on) without taking your hand off of the keyboard.